# Creating a Materialized View with Fast Refrese on Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, materialized-views

I have a weird problem while creating a materialized view on a table with alot of columns, indexes and constraints.

I tried running the command:

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mvX 
PARALLEL BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST AS
SELECT * FROM table_name

After running the command I got: "cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query"
So I run the command:
dbms_mview.explain_mview('SELECT * FROM table_name')
and checked the mv_capabilities_table at REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT, there was the message:
"inline view or subquery in FROM list not supported for this type MV"

1. I have created a matiralized view log on the table with primary key and rowid.
2. I tried to create the same matiralized view on a copy table 
   (CREATE TABLE copy_table_name as select * from table_name)
   and it finish successfully (created a log on this table too)

This view must be FAST REFRESH.
I can't explain why on the copy table it succeeded and on the original table it failed.
help?

Comment: Sounds like this table is actually a view.

Comment: No. it's not. Definitley a table.

Comment: You'd best show all the code by which you create the mv, test the capabilities, and show that it's a table not a view then I think.

Comment: create : CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mvX PARALLEL BUILD IMMEDIATE REFRESH FAST AS SELECT * FROM table_name                          test: call dbms_mview.explain_mview('SELECT * FROM table_name') and select * from mv_capabilities_table.                               type of object : select object_type from user_objects where object_name = 'TABLE_NAME'; (return TABLE)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that one of the columns in your table is a computed/virtual column? If there is then I would investigate the possiblity that it may not work in that case. Its the only reason I can think why the MV Capabilities would give such an error in your case.